Why does my mini-map show there's a floo flame, but there clearly isn't a floo flame?
I'm in the Charms Class in Hogwarts Legacy and my mini-map is showing there is a floo flame in front of me:

But when looking around me, I can't find any floo flame.
Why is the mini-map showing a floo flame in front of me even though there isn't one?

Here are two full photos showing that there clearly aren't any floo flames where the map indicates:



Are you on the correct level?

@pinckerman Not sure. I've seen this with chests now as well. I think like you're asking, the floo flame is probably on a different level.

That's a common problem for a 2D minimap, you know the position but not its height. Check the room below/above if you still see the flame on the map.
